# Transfer local tmux config to remote

Tags: ssh, tmux

I ssh to my remote with:

```
ssh -A ipaddress -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t "tmux new -A -s session"
```

Is there any way to make the remote tmux use my local `~/.tmux.conf`?
I wouldn't be able to copy it over to the tmux.conf on the remote because the volumes for those instances change/die frequently, so I need to do it every time I ssh.

Comment: You can launch tmux on your local computer and then ssh to your remote. Does this work for you?

Comment: the tmux needs to be running on the remote, so all running tmux locally would do is give me some nested tmux sessions

Comment: Okey, why it needs to running on remote? I mean, it might not be possible to use your local conf. You could share it or fetch it from somewhere, and automate the process, but seems to be quite a dirty hack.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen, one of the major selling points of `tmux` is its ability to keep processes running across detaches and network failures. Running tmux locally and `ssh`ing in one of the panes does not provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: No. At least, not without setting up NFS or cron to link your local config file to the remote box.

What you can do is copy it over each time, either as a command right before this

```
scp ~/.tmux.conf ipaddress:~/.tmux.conf
```

or inside your ssh command

```
ssh -A ipaddress -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t "scp <localPCaddress>:~/.tmux.conf ~/.tmux.conf && tmux new -A -s session"
```

You can make a cron job on the local or remote machine to do this scp command often so you don't have to think about it, or you can get NFS set up so the remote system has access to your local files. Tmux cannot read a remote file; it is not designed for that.